# focus to newly opened terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, zsh, focus

I am using gnome-shell 3.14 on archlinux 3.17.3-1.
I have a keyboard shortcut (ctrl+alt+T) to open an xfce4-terminal.

My issue is that when I triger this shortcut the focus is not set the the newly open terminal.
I tried adding to my `.zshrc`

```
[[ -n "$DISPLAY" ]] && wmctrl -i -a $(wmctrl -l | grep Terminal | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

And that worked ... until I tried opening multiples tabs in a terminal.
When opening a new tab, `.zshrc` is run and the focus is moved to the last terminal, wich may not be the open I am currently working on.

So I removed the command from my `.zshrc` file and tried editing the command executed my the shortcut keyboard to

```
xcfe4-terminal&
sleep 0.1
wmctrl -i -a $(wmctrl -l | grep Terminal | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```

I tried increassing the sleep duration, but still it doesn't  do the job (focus isn't set)

Therefore I have 2 question :

- Is it possible to somehow have a script get the window id of the xfce4-terminal running the script ?
- Is it possible to run a command when opening a xfce4-terminal (like if it has in the `.zshrc` even thow it's not in it). I tried the `--execute` option but it doesn't suit my needs as is only runs the focusing command and leaves me with a useless window

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is 3 years old already but I've been suffering from the same problem lately as I moved from plasma to cinnamon. This is what I came up with

Add this to your `.zshrc`(or any other shell config file)

```
xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class 'xfce4-terminal' | tail -n1) &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I've changed my keyboard shortcut to
`xfce4-terminal --disable-server`
and now the terminals seem to get focus properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).